# How do i get photos of user with like / comment count, graph api v2.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

In my application i am getting photos of user from Facebook using graph api request. For this i am making this request:

```
 //Graph API request

 me?fields=photos{album{id},id,from{id},name,created_time,place{id},comments{comment_count},likes,tags{id}}
```

This gives me all photos with comments / likes of photos but not the comment/like count. The like/comment data is array with paging so count cannot be determined by array length.
For getting like/comment count i need to make another batch request for each photo object id.

```
 {photo-object-id}/likes?summary=true
```

Using FQL it was possible in single request, Is there any way to get desired result from single request using graph api v2.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
/me?fields=photos{album{id},id,from{id},name,created_time,place{id},
  comments.summary(1),likes.summary(1),tags{id}}
```

`summary` needs to be set to `1` in order to retrieve the `summary -> total_count` data.

If your were requesting the comments via the comments *edge*, then the syntax would be `/{object-id}/comments?summary=1` – but for the field expansion syntax you are using, `comments.summary(1)` must be used to indicate that you want the `summary` for the comments (and same for the likes)

Comment: How the final URL will look like, actually it is not clear that how to specify summary as 1 in the URL.

Comment: @Shajeel, what specifically is unclear? Final URL for what exactly?

Comment: For example i am getting the comments by doing GET on 'https://graph.facebook.com/cokestudio/posts?fields=comments&access_token=' using Java, how the URL will be needed to changed so that it can send comments count. Thanks.

Comment: Well exactly as I wrote above, `…?fields=comments.summary(1)` And if you are not interested in the content of any individual comments, but the total count only, then you can add `limit=0`, which in field expansion syntax would be `…?fields=comments.limit(0).summary(1)`

Comment: Sorry that is not working, fields i am getting in response are `data`, and `paging`.

Comment: I’d recommend that you use the Graph API Explorer to see that you get the request right first – if it’s working in there, but not when you are doing the request from your Java environment, then you have to search for the error in the latter.